# How to calculate properly average values of a variable in `df1` using data from `df2` at 45-minutes time intervals with `data.table`?

Tags: r, data.table, mean, lubridate

I have a dataframe `df1` that summarizes different observations of an individual `ID` overtime but rounded at fixed 45-minutes intervals starting at `00:00:00` (`00:00:00`, `00:45:00`, etc.). As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(DateTime45=c("2017-07-09 00:00:00","2017-07-09 00:45:00","2017-07-09 02:15:00","2017-07-09 03:45:00"),
                 ID=c("A","A","A","A"),
                 VariableX=c(0,2,0,4))

df1
           DateTime45 ID VariableX
1 2017-07-09 00:00:00  A         0
2 2017-07-09 00:45:00  A         2
3 2017-07-09 02:15:00  A         0
4 2017-07-09 03:45:00  A         4
```

I have another dataframe `df2` in which I have other info (`vedba`) about this individual also overtime, but in this case without 45-minutes time intervals. As an example:

```
df2<- data.frame(DateTime= c("2017-07-08 23:40:57.245","2017-07-08 23:58:12.945","2017-07-09 00:01:00.345","2017-07-09 00:07:12.845","2017-07-09 00:28:34.845","2017-07-09 00:31:46.567","2017-07-09 00:53:21.345","2017-07-09 01:01:34.545","2017-07-09 01:09:12.246","2017-07-09 01:23:12.321","2017-07-09 01:34:26.687","2017-07-09 01:57:08.687","2017-07-09 02:05:23.789","2017-07-09 02:32:24.789","2017-07-09 02:42:34.536","2017-07-09 02:59:00.098","2017-07-09 03:03:01.434","2017-07-09 03:11:38.987","2017-07-09 03:23:31.345","2017-07-09 03:28:21.345","2017-07-09 03:42:53.345"),
                 ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                 vedba=c(1.87,2.3,0.3,0.67,1.3,2.1,3.6,0.1,0.8,1.3,2.4,1.5,1.23,2.02,1.89,0.78,1.11,2.13,1.20,0.34,0.94))
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")

df2

                  DateTime ID vedba
1  2017-07-08 23:40:57.244  A  1.87
2  2017-07-08 23:58:12.944  A  2.30
3  2017-07-09 00:01:00.345  A  0.30
4  2017-07-09 00:07:12.845  A  0.67
.        .          .       .    .
.        .          .       .    .
```

I want to calculate for each row in `df1`, the mean `vedba` using values from `df2`. The key is that I want to consider that for each time in `df1`, the window encompasses between 22 minutes and 30 seconds before and after (that is, `df1$DateTime45` is the central value of the range). For instance, the time-range for `df1[1,1]` (`2017-07-09 00:00:00`) is between `2017-07-08 23:37:30` and  `2017-07-09 00:22:30`.

## In this example, I would expect to get this:

```
df3
           DateTime45 ID VariableX meanVedba n_vedba
1 2017-07-09 00:00:00  A         0 1.2850000       4
2 2017-07-09 00:45:00  A         2 1.7750000       4
3 2017-07-09 02:15:00  A         0 1.5833333       3
4 2017-07-09 03:45:00  A         4 0.8266667       3
```

*Note: I include an `n_vedba` variable to check if the code is taking the right number of rows from `df2`.

## My try was this code:

```
setDT(df1)[, DateTime45 := ymd_hms(DateTime45)]
setDT(df2)[, dt_floor := round_date(ymd_hms(DateTime), unit = "45 mins")]
df3<- df2[df1, .(meanVedba = mean(vedba), 
                                                  n_vedba=.N),
                        on = .(ID, dt_floor = DateTime45), by = .EACHI]

df3

   ID            dt_floor meanVedba n_vedba
1:  A 2017-07-09 00:00:00 0.4850000       2
2:  A 2017-07-09 00:45:00 2.3333333       3
3:  A 2017-07-09 02:15:00        NA       0
4:  A 2017-07-09 03:45:00 0.8266667       3
```

However, as you can see, I don't get what I would expect.

Does anyone know why and how to change the code in order to accomplish what I want?

---

## Extra comment

When I have hour-intervals instead of 45-minutes intervals the code I showed works.

1. I create the dataframes

```
df1<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-07-09 00:00:00","2017-07-09 01:00:00","2017-07-09 02:00:00","2017-07-09 03:00:00","2017-07-09 04:00:00"),
                 ID=c("A","A","A","A","A"),
                 VariableX=c(0,2,0,4,7))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime45, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
df1

             DateTime ID VariableX
1 2017-07-09 00:00:00  A         0
2 2017-07-09 01:00:00  A         2
3 2017-07-09 02:00:00  A         0
4 2017-07-09 03:00:00  A         4
5 2017-07-09 04:00:00  A         7

df2<- data.frame(DateTime= c("2017-07-08 23:40:57.245","2017-07-08 23:58:12.945","2017-07-09 00:01:00.345","2017-07-09 00:07:12.845","2017-07-09 00:28:34.845","2017-07-09 00:31:46.567","2017-07-09 00:53:21.345","2017-07-09 01:01:34.545","2017-07-09 01:09:12.246","2017-07-09 01:23:12.321","2017-07-09 01:34:26.687","2017-07-09 01:57:08.687","2017-07-09 02:05:23.789","2017-07-09 02:32:24.789","2017-07-09 02:42:34.536","2017-07-09 02:59:00.098","2017-07-09 03:03:01.434","2017-07-09 03:11:38.987","2017-07-09 03:23:31.345","2017-07-09 03:28:21.345","2017-07-09 03:42:53.345"),
                 ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                 vedba=c(1.87,2.3,0.3,0.67,1.3,2.1,3.6,0.1,0.8,1.3,2.4,1.5,1.23,2.02,1.89,0.78,1.11,2.13,1.20,0.34,0.94))
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")

df2

               DateTime ID vedba            dt_floor
 1: 2017-07-08 23:40:57  A  1.87 2017-07-09 00:00:00
 2: 2017-07-08 23:58:12  A  2.30 2017-07-09 00:00:00
 3: 2017-07-09 00:01:00  A  0.30 2017-07-09 00:00:00
 4: 2017-07-09 00:07:12  A  0.67 2017-07-09 00:00:00
 .            .          .    .            .
 .            .          .    .            .
```

2. I calculate `vedba` for hourly-bin intervals

```
setDT(df1)[, DateTime45 := ymd_hms(DateTime)]
setDT(df2)[, dt_floor := round_date(ymd_hms(DateTime), unit = "hour")]
df3<- df2[df1, .(meanVedba = mean(vedba), 
                                                  n_vedba=.N),
                        on = .(ID, dt_floor = DateTime), by = .EACHI]

df3

   ID            dt_floor meanVedba n_vedba
1:  A 2017-07-09 00:00:00  1.288000       5
2:  A 2017-07-09 01:00:00  1.580000       5
3:  A 2017-07-09 02:00:00  1.710000       3
4:  A 2017-07-09 03:00:00  1.352857       7
5:  A 2017-07-09 04:00:00  0.940000       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an non-equi join

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df1<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-07-09 00:00:00","2017-07-09 00:45:00","2017-07-09 02:15:00","2017-07-09 03:45:00"),
                 ID=c("A","A","A","A"),
                 VariableX=c(0,2,0,4))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

df2<- data.frame(DateTime= c("2017-07-08 23:40:57.245","2017-07-08 23:58:12.945","2017-07-09 00:01:00.345","2017-07-09 00:07:12.845","2017-07-09 00:28:34.845","2017-07-09 00:31:46.567","2017-07-09 00:53:21.345","2017-07-09 01:01:34.545","2017-07-09 01:09:12.246","2017-07-09 01:23:12.321","2017-07-09 01:34:26.687","2017-07-09 01:57:08.687","2017-07-09 02:05:23.789","2017-07-09 02:32:24.789","2017-07-09 02:42:34.536","2017-07-09 02:59:00.098","2017-07-09 03:03:01.434","2017-07-09 03:11:38.987","2017-07-09 03:23:31.345","2017-07-09 03:28:21.345","2017-07-09 03:42:53.345"),
                 ID=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
                 vedba=c(1.87,2.3,0.3,0.67,1.3,2.1,3.6,0.1,0.8,1.3,2.4,1.5,1.23,2.02,1.89,0.78,1.11,2.13,1.20,0.34,0.94))
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[, date_lo := DateTime - minutes(22) - seconds(30)]
df1[, date_hi := DateTime + minutes(22) + seconds(30)]
df2[df1, .(mean = mean(vedba),
           N = .N), on = .(ID, DateTime <= date_hi, DateTime >= date_lo), .EACHI]

   ID            DateTime            DateTime      mean N
1:  A 2017-07-09 00:22:30 2017-07-08 23:37:30 1.2850000 4
2:  A 2017-07-09 01:07:30 2017-07-09 00:22:30 1.7750000 4
3:  A 2017-07-09 02:37:30 2017-07-09 01:52:30 1.5833333 3
4:  A 2017-07-09 04:07:30 2017-07-09 03:22:30 0.8266667 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought of working around it differently, first I switched your `POSIXct` for`POSIXlt` and I applied it to both `df1` and `df2` ( instead of just `df1`)

So I ran this:

```
df1$DateTime45<- as.POSIXlt(df1$DateTime45, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXlt(df2$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")
```

Then I decided to go for conditions, since you have times, you can check if the difference between each `df2` and your `df1` is greater ( by absolute value) than 22.5 minutes. 
I did it with 2 nested for loops:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1$DateTime45)){
  for (n in 1:length(df2$DateTime)){
  df2$DateTime[abs((df1$DateTime45[i] - df2$DateTime[n])) < seconds_to_period(seconds(22.5*60))][n] <- df1$DateTime45[i]
  }
}
```

Basically so far I overwrote ( converted) all `df2` dates into the relevant `df1`'s.So be mindful that if you want to keep your original `df2` dates and times you should initially run this on a duplicate of `df2`.

Now finally we can calculate the mean vedba and join it to `df1`, again using a simple `for` loop:

```
means <- list()
for (i in 1:length(df1$DateTime45)){
means[[i]]  <- mean(df2[df1$DateTime45[i]==df2$DateTime,]$vedba)
}
df1<- cbind(df1,means = unlist(means))
rm(means)
```

now running `df1` gives us:

```
           DateTime45 ID VariableX     means
1 2017-07-09 00:00:00  A         0 1.2850000
2 2017-07-09 00:45:00  A         2 1.7750000
3 2017-07-09 02:15:00  A         0 1.5833333
4 2017-07-09 03:45:00  A         4 0.8266667
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I am wondering if a for loop will be appropiate in my case since my real dataframe 'df2' has millions of rows and 'df1' several tens of thousands. I will take a look although I will wait in case someone else can let me know how to change the code I tried to solve my goal. I think it should be something silly.

Comment: Also, I forgot to you would need to call the "lubridate" package for this to work.